# MySQL Insert query Â£ issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL insert statements on my site.

If I insert a £ sign into $data through this statement it goes in as a £ - which is fine.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `applicants` (`id`, `data`, .....) 
VALUES ('0', '".addslashes($data )."',... ";
```

In the second statement the £ in $data goes in as Â£
The insert statement is

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO applicants SET   
`data` = :data,
........  
$stmt->bindParam(':data', $data);
```

Might the Â£ problem be caused by the way $stmt / bindParam insert statement?

Comment: What good is that call to ?`addslashes()` meant to do?

Comment: Apart from that this actually looks like an encoding issue to me. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: I've worked through the possible problem areas. It appears to be UTF-8 'all the way'. Just wondered if there might be something else I was missing.